# How can i use the python of the anaconda environment when I use "rosrun" to run a python file in ROS Noetic

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, ros

I want use the python of the anaconda environment when I use ROS Noetic.
But I found that even if the virtual environment is activated at the terminal，whether "rosrun" or "roslaunch" uses the Python for my Ubuntu system,like"usr/bin/python3".However,when I use "python script_name.py" in the same terminal,it can use the python of the anaconda environment correctly.Is this normal？If anaconda is not used, deploying deep learning in ROS may not feel very convenient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing rospkg inside your conda environment. This should solve the issue of using rosrun when inside conda (making use of python in the Virtual Environment).

```
pip install rospkg
```